# Android - Running multiple Database Instances

Tags: android, sqlite, instance, multiple-instances

I am developing an android app. In that app, I have to add and get the data from my database constantly.

I using three separate threads to do so. I do not think I have a thread problem as in my DDMS I can monitor the threads opening But what I think, I am failing to grasp is the Database instances.

**For example,**

I have a method which shall construct a filename which is made up of the value in a cell of one table + "_" + value of a cell in another table.  So, I have this method which calling two other methods each with the task to go to the database and get that value.

Problem is that I am not sure how I should create an instance.Below you can see that for each method I have created a separate instance of the same database and then closed that.
In this AsyncTaskRunner class I have many methods of the same as below which are doing their own task, but open a different instance name for the same database each time.

This seems very wrong.I would imagine that as soon as the class opens I could open ONE single instance of the database and then not close it until Destroy() so that all methods can do their thing.

What can I do better?

**Here is my code :**

```
public String evaluateATable(String filenamePrefix){
    
    SQLDatabase getATableData = new SQLDatabase(mContext);
    getATableData.open();

    String aRowId = SQLDatabase.evalATable(filenamePrefix);

    getATableData.close();

    if(aRowId != null){
        return aRowId;
    }
    return null;
}

public String evaluateLTable(String filenamePrefix){
    
    SQLDatabase getLtabledata = new SQLDatabase(mContext);
    getLtabledata.open();

    String lRowId = SQLDatabase.evalLTable(filenamePrefix);

    getLtabledata.close();

    if(lRowId != null){
        return lRowId;
    }       
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It looks like the answer may be to create a Global instance of this database?  From what I have found it looks like I can open the database then modify all of my methods and remove all of the new instances and opn, close ops and the do as I will with the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do one thing ,you have to declare SQLDatabase and create instance of it once, and then use that in all method

just like below

```
Public class test extends Activity {

SQLDatabase getATableData;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  SQLDatabase getATableData = new SQLDatabase(this);
 } 

public String evaluateATable(String filenamePrefix){

getATableData.open();

String aRowId = SQLDatabase.evalATable(filenamePrefix);

getATableData.close();

if(aRowId != null){
    return aRowId;
}
return null;
}

public String evaluateLTable(String filenamePrefix){

getLtabledata.open();

String lRowId = SQLDatabase.evalLTable(filenamePrefix);

getLtabledata.close();

if(lRowId != null){
    return lRowId;
}

return null;
}
```

Comment: will this also apply to this AsyncTaskRunner Class?